# Updating an existing package's dependency version?

Tags: javascript, npm, mean-stack

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 trying to install this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stanford-corenlp

However, whenever I try to do so, it tries to install node-java 0.5.5 as a dependency which fails (gives me node-gyp errors).

I looked this issue up, and it's fixed by using a newer version of node-java. 0.6.1 seems to work fine, but I don't know how to update the dependency to install the stanford-corenlp package.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
"node-java": "^0.6.1"
```

in 'dependencies' of your package.json file. Then run `npm install`. This will install the right version of node-java.

Then try to install standford-corenlp. If they didn't hardcode the node-java version in their package.json, you should be alright

Comment: Yes, it is listed in their package.json. This is what I was wondering. How would I go about changing that?

Comment: In their package.json I see "java": "^0.6.0" so what i said should work. Did you try it ? Did you get an error ? What version of stanford-corenlp are you trying to install ? A very ugly solution would be to fork their project, and change the package.json...

Comment: Sorry, my power went out. That was unfortunate. I am trying to install the latest version, I did try what you suggested, and it continues to try and install "java@0.5.5" and I get the appropriate errors for that version. Once I fork it, how do I actually run npm install with mine?